# How to make TestNG print detail message about the failure

Tags: testng

My testNG failed with simple message:

```
[TestNG] [ERROR]
Cannot instantiate class com.xyz.AbcTest
```

However I don't know why it cannot instantiate the class. How can I make TestNG print out the detail information or the error stack in this case?

Comment: Version of TestNg & any stack trace in console ? Here Take a look at https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/internal/InstanceCreator.java May give some information

Comment: if you are running through IDE it must have printed the stacktrace. Additionally, enable reporter output and the testng reports should also show full stacktrace.

Comment: @RahulL
- testNg version: 6.x
- no stack trace in console

Comment: @MrunalGosar if I run it in IDE yes, I can seee the stacktrace. But I need see that in the remote console. How can I enable reporter output?

Comment: @GelinLuo so if you are able to view stacktrace in IDE then that should tell you why it is not able to instantiate your test. Also can you post the class which it is not able to instantiate and full stacktrace from IDE

Comment: @GelinLuo I deleted my answer: its main point was the use of the `-1` value as the one you need to provide to run TestNG in verbose mode but I was revising the actual source code of the library and surefire and I am not sure this functionality is longer supported. Please, sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the maven-surefire-plugin for execution of the TestNG test . For enabling the full stack trace on the console we need to set [trimStackTrace](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#trimStackTrace) to false

**trimStackTrace** : Whether to trim the stack trace in the reports to just the lines within the test, or show the full trace.
Default value is: true.
User property is: trimStackTrace.*

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>

    </plugin>
```

With above setting for maven project you should be able to see full stack trace.

**Below are remote console outputs with trimStackTrace :**

For : **trimStackTrace:true**

```
[ERROR] com.interfaces.TestClass.testing[Edge, org.testng.TestRunner@28467629](2)  Time elapsed: 0.008 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.interfaces.TestClass.testing(TestClass.java:32)

[ERROR] com.interfaces.TestClass.testing[Chrome, org.testng.TestRunner@28467629](2)  Time elapsed: 0.009 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.interfaces.TestClass.testing(TestClass.java:32)

[INFO]

---------------------------------------------------
```

For **trimStackTrace :false**

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.477 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] com.interfaces.TestClass.testing[Edge, org.testng.TestRunner@2dc7f489](2)  Time elapsed: 0.014 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.interfaces.TestClass.testing(TestClass.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
        at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
        at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:77)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:15)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can enable testng logger by using log4testng.properties file in the src/main/resources .

https://github.com/qmetry/qtm-QAF-MAVEN-example/blob/master/resources/log4testng.properties

Also use verbose="10" in the testng xml file.